# Chart not rendering in viewport in IE and FF

Tags: extjs

The chart is not renderig. It is really simple.
In Chrome everything is ok.
What can be the problem?
Here is the link: http://174.122.19.123/~mishkan/test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no doctype for the page, try adding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

As the first line of HTML for the test page.

Update from comments below: ExtJS charts use Flash. If a particular browser doesn't have the Flash plug-in installed, the charts wont display.

Comment: Do you have the Flash plug-in installed on IE and FireFox? The ExtJS charts use Flash and wont show up if its not installed for that particular browser.